# Insert section in table view with Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to insert a new section in tableview

```
let oldIns = insertCounter //insertCounter = 40
insertCounter += Int(INSERT_MESSAGES) // insertCounter = 80
let minn = min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
print(minn) // minn = 80
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, minn)) as IndexSet, with: .top)
tableView.endUpdates()


override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let a = min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
    print(a) // after call insertSections a = 80
    return min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 5
}
```

I get an error:

> Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections
>   contained in the table view after the update (80) must be equal to the
>   number of sections contained in the table view before the update (40),
>   plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (80 inserted,
>   0 deleted).

When i do the following:

```
tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(oldIns, minn)) as IndexSet, with: .top)
```

I get the error:

> exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to
>   insert section 80 but there are only 80 sections after the update'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated but `NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, minn)) as IndexSet` is horrible *objective-c-ish*. This is Swift: `IndexSet(integersIn: 0..<minn)`. First you have to update the data source array, then insert the rows/sections. And `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is pointless in this case.

Comment: @vadian yeah, thank you so much, u can add as answer

Answer (score 0):

as the error described, your old sections count is 40, you insert 80 sections, so the updated sections count should be 120.

```swift
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    let a = min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
    print(a) // after call insertSections a = 80
    // you should return 120 instead of 80 here.
    return min(insertCounter, Int(dbmessages.count))
}
```

or your could insert like this

```swift
tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(oldIns, minn)) as IndexSet, with: .top)
```